# Verilog Function Application

Tags: verilog, modelsim

I get this compilation error when using ModelSim on the below code

> near "assign": syntax error, unexpected assign, expecting IDENTIFIER
>   or TYPE_IDENTIFIER or NETTYPE_IDENTIFIER.

```
`define WIDTH 8  

    module Parityfunc(input [`WIDTH-1:0] i_data, output o_parity_out, input parity_type);


    function parity (input [`WIDTH-1:0] data, input parity_type);
        begin
            if (parity_type)        // even parity
                parity <= ^data;
            else if (!parity_type)  // odd parity
                parity <= ~(^data);
        end 

    endfunction : 

        assign o_parity_out = parity(i_data, parity_type);

    endmodule // Parityfunc
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to remove the colon after `endfunction`.

```
`define WIDTH 8  

module Parityfunc(input [`WIDTH-1:0] i_data, output o_parity_out, input parity_type);


function parity (input [`WIDTH-1:0] data, input parity_type);
    begin
        if (parity_type)        // even parity
            parity <= ^data;
        else if (!parity_type)  // odd parity
            parity <= ~(^data);
    end 

endfunction

    assign o_parity_out = parity(i_data, parity_type);

endmodule // Parityfunc
```

Another solution is to add the function name after the colon:

```
endfunction : parity
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2012, 13.4 *Functions*.